# Specific hosting or virtual machine?

Tags: web-hosting, php, looking-for-hosting, amazon-ec2, node-js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm searching for hosting for the back-end and web client of an application that uses node.js and mongodb on the back-end and PHP on the web client.
There are many options for hosting node:

- [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/)
- [Nodester](http://nodester.com/)
- [Joyent](http://www.joyent.com/)

For PHP nearly all hosting options are able of rendering PHP, for mongodb the node hostings allow databases as well.

The project will have low usage, would it be better to use a VPS hosting where I can install all the software needed (PHP, Node and Mongo) like AmazonsEC2 micro instances?

Are there any good alternatives to Amazon EC2?